# How to use joins and groupby in laravel and to iterate through?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a shops table and a sections table. The shop may be located under many sections. 
The problem is that, if the shop belongs to more than 1 section, I can't view all sections. 
The DB is as following:

Shop table

```
id  |  shopname

1   | KazaBlanka
2   | Adiddas
3   | Kentaky
```

---

Sections Table

```
id  |  Sectionname

1   | Clothes
2   | Shoes
3   | Foods
```

---

ShopSection (The link) table

```
id  |  sectionId   |    ShopId

1   | 1            |    1
2   | 1            |    2
3   | 2            |    1
4   | 2            |    2
5   | 3            |    3
```

In my controller I try to retrieve data with a query like that:

```
$data = Shops::join('shopsection','shopsection.shopid','=','shop.id')
    ->join('sections','sections.id','=','shopsection.sectionid')        
    ->select('shop.id as id', 'sectionname as sectionname', 
    'shopname as shopname')  
    ->groupBy('shop.id')      
    ->paginate(15);
```

and in my view I show data as following

```
@foreach($data as $row)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $row->shopname }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->shopsection }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

if the shop belongs to more than one section, this shows me the first section only.
How can I loop throw the result data again to (every shop) to show the sections inside?? Do I need to use groupBy??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, why don't you use Model Relations ? It's a powerfull feature in Laravel: read [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.1/eloquent#many-to-many) how to properly define such type of relation.

When your relations would be defined, your query code would be simplified to:

```
$data = Shops::with('sections')->paginate(15);
```

When you are specifying the relation name **sections**, Laravel makes proper joins, and in the result data, you would have a key **sections** that would contain a Collection of sections, so you could loop through them.

Comment: Thanks. It is a good method I didn't know about. But it didn't solve my problem. Now for each shop I get as many rows as sections have been added to this shop. I need a method to make only one, main, row for each shop then to itirate inside this main one to show sections belong to it. @Vit Kos

Comment: It is OK. I got it. It was a redundant data in my data base. Every thing is working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Vit Kos.

Now I updated my shop model to have this:

```
public function sections()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Sections');
}
```

then in controller I retrieve data this easy way:

```
$data = Shops::->with('sections')
                ->orderBy('sortby')
                ->paginate(15);
```

and in the view I can access sections like this:

```
@foreach($data as $row)
    <td>{{ $row->shop_name }}</td>
    <td> 
    @foreach ($row->sections as $section)
        {{ $section->section_name}} 
    @endforeach
    </td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Glad you have it working. To speed up queries I would recomend that you specify the keys on your relations, so that the framework should not process the guessing mechanism.  `return $this->belongsToMany('Role', 'user_roles', 'user_id', 'foo_id');`